# Convert the following regular expression into NFA

Tags: theory, automata, nfa

Convert the following regular expression into NFA:
ab((ba)* + a*)

Answer (score 1):

There's a nifty algorithm for this that builds the NFA one step at a time based on the operations on the regular expression. The outermost operators here are concatenation: your regular expression is the concatenation of three terms:

```
(a)(b)((ba)* + a*)
```

This means there is an NFA that is the concatenation of three NFAs that accepts the language generated by this expression. NFAs for languages (a) and (b) are trivial:

```
L = {a}
q0--a-->q1

L = {b}
q2--b-->q3
```

Suppose we later get an NFA for the language (ba)* + a*, and its start symbol is q4. Then our NFA will look like this (unmarked transitions are epsilon/lambda/empty):

```
q0--a-->q1----->q2--b-->q3----->q4
```

We can repeat the algorithm for the subexpression (ba)* + a*. The outermost operation here is +; that means there's an NFA that looks like this, where q5 and q6 are starting states for the subexpressions on the left and right of the + operator:

```
q4----->q5
 |
 |
 V
 q6
```

An NFA for a* is easy enough:

```
q6-a-\
 ^   |
 \___/
```

I'll skip a couple of steps and just write down an NFA for (ba)*, but the algorithm (same as used to prove equivalence of NFAs and REs) has a simple rule for this too:

```
q5--b-->q7
 ^      |
 |      a
 \______/
```

Putting it al together gives this:

```
q0--a-->q1----->q2--b-->q3----->q4----->q5--b-->q7
                                 |       ^      |
                                 |       |      a
                                 V       \______/
                                 q6-a-\
                                  ^   |
                                  \___/
```